# How can I load thousands of records into a JavaScript-array instead of HTML and then output them with javaScript, so that I can maintain the speed

Tags: php, sql, dynamic-programming

I made this code, which shows the first hundred records (total of 1600). I don't want to show all 1600 records in one card because the loading would take to long. Can someone help me to load these records into a JS-array?

```
<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-01">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
                            aria-controls="collapseOne" style="color:#000; text-decoration: none;">
                        Rows 0-100
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <?php
                    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pw");
                    mysqli_select_db($con, 'db');
                    $sql = "select * from $ic limit 0,100";
                    $records = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                    ?>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>URL</th>
                            <th>Anchor</th>
                            <th>Backlink</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Build by</th>
                            <th>Edits</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>

                        <?php

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
                            echo "<tr><form action=update.php?id=" . $ic . " method=post>";
                            echo "<td><input type=text name=id1 value='" . $row['id'] . "'>";
                            echo "<td><input type=text name=url1 value='" . $row['url'] . "'></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=text name=anchor1 value='" . $row['anchor'] . "'></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=text name=backlink1 value='" . $row['backlink'] . "'></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=date name=datum1 value='" . $row['datum'] . "'></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=text name=ingedienddoor1 value='" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=text disabled name=ingedienddoor value='" . $row['ingedienddoor'] . "'></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=text name=opmerking1 value='" . $row['opmerking'] . "'></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=color name='status1' value='" . $row['status'] . "' list=presetColors style=width:100px; />
                                <datalist id=\"presetColors\">
                                    <option value=\"#ff0000\"/>
                                    <option value=\"#ff9900\"/>
                                    <option value=\"#00ff00\"/>
                                </datalist></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=text name=prijs1 value='" . $row['prijs'] . "'></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=submit value=update></td>";
                            echo "</form></tr>";
                        }

                        ?>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is what the code above looks like: http://prntscr.com/q60y5m

Comment: you can use ajax calls to get and append data to it.

Comment: You need pagination or just simply append remaining rows to table?

Comment: I would advise you, assuming you use Jquery to use Jquery datatables.

Comment: Someone asked a ver similar question just a few hours ago. See if you can find it.

Comment: You can also load all the rows at once, but output them to a JavaScript-array instead of HTML. This makes it a lot faster for the browser to handle. Then output them with javaScript to the document in a aset of 10's.

Comment: Just output the lines to an JavaScript array inside <script></script> tags and then create JavaScript-function that reads that array and outputs the lines to the <table>.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the solution for your question. you can use this code. In html code we are displaying first 100 records, when the time of scroll downs it will load next 100 records using ajax until 1600 records.

```
 //html code
 <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-01">
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
                        aria-controls="collapseOne" style="color:#000; text-decoration: none;">
                    Rows 0-100
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                <?php
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pw");
                mysqli_select_db($con, 'db');
                $sql = "select * from $ic limit 0,100";
                $records = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                ?>
                <table id="tbl">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>URL</th>
                        <th>Anchor</th>
                        <th>Backlink</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Build by</th>
                        <th>Edits</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
                        echo "<tr><form action=update.php?id=" . $ic . " method=post>";
                        echo "<td><input type=text name=id1 value='" . $row['id'] . "'>";
                        echo "<td><input type=text name=url1 value='" . $row['url'] . "'></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=text name=anchor1 value='" . $row['anchor'] . "'></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=text name=backlink1 value='" . $row['backlink'] . "'></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=date name=datum1 value='" . $row['datum'] . "'></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=`text` name=ingedienddoor1 value='" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=text disabled name=ingedienddoor value='" . $row['ingedienddoor'] . "'></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=text name=opmerking1 value='" . $row['opmerking'] . "'></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=color name='status1' value='" . $row['status'] . "' list=presetColors style=width:100px; />
                            <datalist id=\"presetColors\">
                                <option value=\"#ff0000\"/>
                                <option value=\"#ff9900\"/>
                                <option value=\"#00ff00\"/>
                            </datalist></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=text name=prijs1 value='" . $row['prijs'] . "'></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=submit value=update></td>";
                        echo "</form></tr>";
                    }

                    ?>
                 </tbody>
                 <input type="hidden" id="newpage" value="2" />
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

create new file as functions.php and paste following code in that

```
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pw");
     mysqli_select_db($con, 'db');
     $limit=100;
     $ic=$_POST['ic'];
     if(isset($_POST['page']))
     {
      $page = $_POST['page'];
      $newpage=$page+1;
     }
else
{
    $page=2;
    $newpage=$page+1;
}
$sql = "select * from $ic limit $page,$limit";
$records = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$tr='';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) 
    {
        $tr.="<tr><form action=update.php?id=" . $ic . " method=post>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=text name=id1 value='" . $row['id'] . "'>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=text name=url1 value='" . $row['url'] . "'></td>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=text name=anchor1 value='" . $row['anchor'] . "'></td>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=text name=backlink1 value='" . $row['backlink'] . "'></td>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=date name=datum1 value='" . $row['datum'] . "'></td>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=text name=ingedienddoor1 value='" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'></td>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=text disabled name=ingedienddoor value='" . $row['ingedienddoor'] . "'></td>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=text name=opmerking1 value='" . $row['opmerking'] . "'></td>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=color name='status1' value='" . $row['status'] . "' list=presetColors style=width:100px; /><datalist id=\"presetColors\"><option value=\"#ff0000\"/><option value=\"#ff9900\"/><option value=\"#00ff00\"/></datalist></td>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=text name=prijs1 value='" . $row['prijs'] . "'></td>";
        $tr.="<td><input type=submit value=update></td>";
        $tr.="</form></tr>";
    }
echo json_encode(array("rows"=>$tr,"page"=>$newpage));
```

Paste below js code in you html code

```
//Js code
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        getData()
    });
});
function getData()
{
    var page = $("#newpage").val();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'functions.php',
            data: {page:page,ic:'<?php echo $ic;?>'},
            type:'POST',
            datatype:'json',
            success : function(data)
            {
                var rows = data.rows;
                $("#tbl tbody").append(rows);
                $("#newpage").val(data.page)
            }
            });
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203623/discussion-on-answer-by-chandrashekar-how-to-load-1600-rows-without-affecting-th).